# C# Обновление Label из цикла

Tags: c#

Есть цикл загрузки данных в методе downloadToClass:

```
        private void downloadToClass(List<string> Files)
    {
        MsForm _MSForm;

        if (lMFile.Count != 0)
        {
            _MSForm = new MsForm("Предупреждение!", "Добавить файлы или создать новый список?", "Добавить", "Новый", "Отмена");
            _MSForm.ShowDialog();
            if (_MSForm.DialogResult == DialogResult.No) Clear();
            if (_MSForm.DialogResult == DialogResult.Cancel) return;
        }

        Files.Sort(new LogicalStringComparer());

        if (Files.Count == 0)
        {
            _MSForm = new MsForm("Ошибка [151]", "Файлы не найдены!");
            _MSForm.ShowDialog();
            return;
        }

        if (lMFile.Count != 0)
        {
            foreach (string STR in Files)
            {
                bool b = true;
                foreach (mFiles buff in lMFile) //Проверка на повторную загрузку тех же данных
                {
                    if (buff.News.Path == STR)
                    {
                        b = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (b) lMFile.Add(new mFiles(STR, lMFile.Count));
                //lTFile.Text = "Файлов загружено: " + lMFile.Count;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (string STR in Files)
            {
                lMFile.Add(new mFiles(STR, lMFile.Count));
                //lTFile.Text = "Файлов загружено: " + lMFile.Count;
            }
        }
    }
```

Нужно после каждого добавленного в класс "файла" обновлять lTFile.Text (lTFile - Lebel), и задавать текст формата: "Файлов загружено: " + lMFile.Count
Проблема в том, что программа форма повисает пока идет цикл, а lebel обновится только после завершения цикла. Суть показать, что программа работает, а не зависла.

Попробовал создание потока, посредством BeginInvoke:

```
            var action = new Action<List<string>>(downloadToClass);
        var result = action.BeginInvoke(Files, null, null);
        while (!result.IsCompleted) lTFile.Text = "Файлов загружено: " + lMFile.Count;
```

Эффект тот же...

P.S. До этого была идея вызвать другую форму, и в ней вывести progresbar, но форма даже не появлялась... (До сих пор стремлюсь к этому варианту, но думаю проблема не в вызове формы, а в том, что программа занята циклом...)

Comment: Ну, проблема понятна, вы выполняете блокирующую операцию в UI-потоке. А какой у вас размер списка? Почему ваш метод выполняется не мгновенно?

Comment: 1. Список (list) содержит пути к файлам, а их может быть 10 или 210

Comment: 2. Список lMFile состоит из элементов моего класса mFiles, а в его конструктор заложен алгоритм сбора данных из файла. И это может занять 2-3 секунды если файлов около 100. Я же хочу не пугать людей в случае если файлов будет несколько сотен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ предложенный от VladD, тоже как вариант решения, но...
Если у вас во время выполнения данной процедуры больше **ничего не должно выполняться в программе параллельно этой задаче**, тогда добавьте в необходимое место обновление формы.

```
Form.Update();
```

Думаю, что в вашем варианте это:

```
lTFile.Text = "Файлов загружено: " + lMFile.Count;
_MSForm.Update();
```

Метод формы Update() перерисовывает форму и все дочерние элементы, но бывают проблемы с некоторыми - тогда нужно будет поискать метод перерисовки для конкретного компонента. Но думаю в вашем случае все получится.

Comment: Спасибо большое, Update() действительно помог... Только пришлось использовать this.Update().
Однако, если я захочу создать другое окно (форму) и там вырисовывать процесс на progresbar'e то мне придется использовать второй поток?

Comment: + это повысило время выполнения раза в 2-3, в моем случае, если и обновлять то не всю форму, а необходимый элемент. lTFile.Text = "Файлов загружено: " + lMFile.Count;
                    this.lTFile.Update();

Comment: Многопоточность используется для одновременного выполнения нескольких процедур. В вашей задаче выполнять одновременно 1 процедуру, просто в каждом такте выполнения вам надо обновлять/перерисовывать методом Update() необходимую форму/компонент в зависимости от ситуации.
Форму отображения процесса выполнения можно открыть до запуска цикла, а в метод/цикл ее передать как параметр или если она глобально доступа, то обращаться напрямую. Так вы сможете ее перерисовывать.

Comment: Сейчас попробую

Comment: Да, спасибо за помощь. 1)Создал форму 2)Показал форму 3)Отрисовал форму. А дальше выполнять обновление нужных мне элементов и прорисовку их в цикле. + Закрыть форму в конце.

Answer (score 0):

Вынесите вашу длинную операцию в другой поток, и передавайте сообщения о прогрессе операции в основной. Это должно выглядеть как-то так:

```
void Operation(IProgress<int> progress, List<string> Files, List<mFiles> lMFile)
{
    Files.Sort(new LogicalStringComparer());

    if (lMFile.Count != 0)
    {
        foreach (string STR in Files)
        {
            bool b = true;
            foreach (mFiles buff in lMFile) //Проверка на повторную загрузку тех же данных
            {
                if (buff.News.Path == STR)
                {
                    b = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (b) lMFile.Add(new mFiles(STR, lMFile.Count));
            progress.Report(lMFile.Count);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (string STR in Files)
        {
            lMFile.Add(new mFiles(STR, lMFile.Count));
            progress.Report(lMFile.Count);
        }
    }
}
```

Ну и сделайте вашу основную процедуру асинхронной.

```
async Task downloadToClass(List<string> Files)
{
    MsForm _MSForm;

    if (lMFile.Count != 0)
    {
        _MSForm = new MsForm("Предупреждение!", "Добавить файлы или создать новый список?",
                             "Добавить", "Новый", "Отмена");
        _MSForm.ShowDialog();
        if (_MSForm.DialogResult == DialogResult.No) Clear();
        if (_MSForm.DialogResult == DialogResult.Cancel) return;
    }

    if (Files.Count == 0)
    {
        _MSForm = new MsForm("Ошибка [151]", "Файлы не найдены!");
        _MSForm.ShowDialog();
        return;
    }

    var progress = new Progress<int>(k => lTFile.Text = "Файлов загружено: " + k);
    await Task.Run(() => Operation(progress, Files, lMFile);
}
```

Comment: До этого еще не сталкивался с async. VS выдает предупреждение при вызове метода downloadToClass(Files); [Поскольку этот вызов не ожидается, выполнение текущего метода продолжается до завершения вызова. Попробуйте применить оператор await к результату вызова.]

Comment: И во время того как данные грузятся в другом потеке, старый поток продолжает работать и при попытке загрузить данные уже из класса в DataGridView, загружает пустоту. (Так как данных еще нет) Как приостановить свой поток?

Comment: @Opossum: Ну да, выполняется в фоне. А как вы его вызываете?

Comment: @Opossum: Ну да, вы должны дождаться окончания выполнения (`await`).